# If you don't enter a 1st vote for elections, do your 2nd and 3rd votes still count?

Tags: support, election

I found myself curious because I placed a vote for my 3rd choice, and couldn't decide between #1 and #2 until a moderator questionnaire got filled out by both candidates. Then I forgot to come back to place my #1 and #2 votes.

In such cases, does my 3rd vote count as my 1st vote? Or not count at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We confirmed during a recent election on Workplace that the first vote *on your ballot* counts as your first choice, regardless of its slot.  (Ditto the second, so if you vote #2 and #3 only, they become #1 and #2.)

As far as the voting engine is concerned, missing a #1 choice because you didn't fill one out is the same as missing it because your first-choice candidate was eliminated.